# Normalize SQL - Set column to primary key identifier based on matching string from another table

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

*Table Visualization*

**oldCars**

```
carId | color | etc    // Column Name
1     | red   | *
2     | blue  | *
3     | teal  | *
4     | red   | *
```

**carColors**

```
colorId | color | etc  // Column Names
1       | blue  | *
2       | teal  | *
3       | red   | *
```

**newCars**

```
carId | colorId | etc  // Column Names
```

I am trying to normalize a database. What I would like to do is insert into `newCars` each row from `oldCars` but instead of using just the color name, I want to use the primary key `colorId` from the `carColors` table.

*The result would look like this...*

**newCars**

```
carId | colorId | etc  // Column Names
1     | 3       | *
2     | 1       | *
3     | 2       | *
4     | 3       | *
```

This sort of statement seems trivial, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple `JOIN` using the color name as the joining condition.

```
INSERT INTO newCars
SELECT o.carID, c.colorID, o.etc
FROM oldCars AS o
JOIN carColors AS c ON c.color = o.color
```